# RDS Postgres, tup_returned > tup_fetched, the data might not be properly indexed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to diagnose a high traffic and problematic table(it has an abysmal cache hit rate 0.035)

Given the following sentence from AWS RDS docs:

> The tup_returned metric shows the number of rows read. The tup_fetched metric shows the number of rows returned to the client. If tup_returned is significantly larger than tup_fetched, the data might not be properly indexed. Also, your table statistics might not be current.

Our table statistics are up to date.

The following metrics are from a high read event:

```
tup_returned = 13_432_903.37
tup_fetched =     258_434.83

> tup_returned/tup_fetched
=> 51.977914006405406
```

This table has an index for almost every column. Is there such a thing as over indexing? Not properly indexed means we're using btree, but should be using gin etc, is this a correct statement? There are materialized views on this table because performance was so bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This table has an index for almost every column

This doesn't mean any of them are being used.

> is there such a thing as over indexing?

There certainly is, but it is not the problem in your case.

> Not properly indexed means we're using btree but should be using gin etc, is this a correct statement?

No, it's not. The statement means that the optimiser often does not find a useful index and has to scan the heap (table), then throw away the majority of rows because the don't match the query conditions.

`tup_returned` and `tup_fetched` are database-wide metrics. You need to identify the specific queries that cause the problem. From the `pg_stat_user_tables` you can obtain `seq_scan` and `seq_tup_read`, as well as `idx_scan` and `idx_tup_fetch` to find the tables from which a large portion of rows is frequently retrieved. Similarly, high values in `rows` and `shared_blks_read` of [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) will let you find the queries with high I/O.

You will then use [`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) with the worst queries to determine why they are so bad.

Once you have that information, you can post a question here, following [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions), if you need help with any particular query.